# Optimization problem with a constraint

Tags: optimization, market-microstructure

Consider the following maximization problem $$\max_{\{\tau(\cdot),q(\cdot)\}}\int_{\underline{\theta}}^{\bar{\theta}}\left(\theta q(\theta)-\dfrac{\gamma\sigma^{2}}{2}q^2(\theta)-\tau(\theta)\right)f(\theta)d\theta$$
subject to $$\int_{\underline{\theta}}^{\bar{\theta}}\left(\tau(\theta)-v(\theta)q(\theta)\right)f(\theta)d\theta\geq\underline{\pi}$$
where $\theta=s-\gamma\sigma^2 I$ and has a bounded support, $[\underline{\theta},\bar{\theta}]$, $\gamma\sigma^2>0$ and $s\sim N(\bar{s},\sigma_1^{2})$ and $I\in\mathbb{R}$. The functions $u(\cdot)$, $\tau(\cdot)$ and $q(\cdot)$ are linear with respect to $\theta$, $\underline{\pi}$ is a constant and $f(\theta)$ is the pdf of the normal distribution.

This is a problem of the Biais, Rochet and Martimont paper in 2000 [problem in subsection $3.5$](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/David_Martimort/publication/5106795_Competing_Mechanisms_in_a_Commun_Value_Environment/links/02e7e537b9f33af0a3000000.pdf). I am a little confused with the constraint and I can not understand how to solve it. It is not obvious to me. Thank you in advance!

$\underline{Hint:}$ They do not explicitly assumme that the $\theta$ variable follows a normal distribution, but this has nothing to do with the optimization problem.

$\underline{Comments?:}$ I know it has been time but, to sum up the paper of Biais, Rochet and Martimont uses the calculus of variations, isn't it? I am a little confused because I thought that you can use the calculus of variations only in case you have the time dimension in your problem. As I can see, and correct me if I am mistaken, by this paper, their model is some type of a static one, isn't it?

Comment: Would it be helpful to re-state my problem? Is something that it is not clear? What should I do?

Comment: Can you include a link to the paper? People will be able to consult to help.

Comment: @Daneel Olivaw of course I can!!

Comment: good luck with the rest of the paper..

Comment: Although it starts with a classic and simple model it becomes more and more tricky...but it is a nice paper!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should think of the integral as you would of a sum. Then the usual Lagrangian approach seems very natural.

\begin{align} 
  \mathcal{L} &= \int_\underline{\theta}^\overline{\theta} \left( \theta q(\theta) - \frac{\gamma\sigma^2}{2}q^2(\theta) - \tau(\theta) \right) f(\theta) d \theta + \lambda \left(\int_{\underline{\theta}}^\overline{\theta} (\tau(\theta) - v(\theta) q(\theta)) f(\theta) d\theta \right)\\
&= \int_\underline{\theta}^\overline{\theta} \left( \theta q(\theta) - \frac{\gamma\sigma^2}{2}q^2(\theta) - \tau(\theta) + \lambda(\tau(\theta) - v(\theta) q(\theta)) \right) f(\theta) d\theta - \lambda \underline{\pi}\\
&= \int_\underline{\theta}^\overline{\theta} \left( \theta q(\theta) - \frac{\gamma\sigma^2}{2}q^2(\theta) - \lambda v(\theta) q(\theta) + (\lambda-1)\tau(\theta) \right) f(\theta) d\theta - \lambda \underline{\pi}
\end{align}

Now, simply treat $\theta$ as a summation index and write the first-order conditions case-by-case (for each $\theta$):

\begin{align}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial q(\theta)} \mathcal{L} & = \theta - \gamma\sigma^2 q(\theta) - \lambda v(\theta)  = 0 \\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial \tau(\theta)} \mathcal{L} & = \lambda - 1 = 0
\end{align}

In the footnote 16 the authors make the assumption that the participation constraint is binding, and therefore $\lambda^* > 0$ and therefore 
$$ \lambda^* = 1, $$
according to the second first-order condition. Substituting the value of $\lambda^*$ into the first condition you get
\begin{equation}
     q^*(\theta) = \frac{\theta - v(\theta)}{\gamma \sigma^2}.
\end{equation}

The assumptions made in the last paragraph of the section ensure that $\tau^*(\theta)$ is non-zero almost everywhere (for all possible $\theta$ except for one arbitrary value, which they denote $\theta_0$ - it must depend on the exact functional form of $v$ should you choose one).

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: It was my pleasure :)

Comment: I hope someday, I can be so good to help someone also!

Comment: I know it has been time but, to sum up the paper of Biais, Rochet and Martimont uses the calculus of variations, isn't it? I am a llitle confused because I thought that you can use the calculus of variations only in case you have the time dimension in your problem. As I can see, and correcet If I am mistaken, by this paper, their model is some type of a static one, isn.t it?

Comment: This is calculus of variations, that's right. They treat the type parameter as time, it is very common. In fact, you can even apply calculus of variations to multidimensional states, that include not only time but also for example physical coordinates etc.

Comment: I see, but it is like they do not take into account the rime dimension explicitly. I was hoping to apply some similar theory like this is a static model. However, I am still trying to find if anyone else uses these tools for some similar argument...

Comment: Check adverse selection principal-agent models with a continuum of types. E.g. Laffont Matrimony "Theory of incentives" textbook, appendix 3.1 on page 134 -.... BMR do not have time dimension.

Comment: Thank you for everything!

Comment: To be honest, It is nice that they do not have the time dimension, That is what I am searching for, but I had no idea that there is something of what I am looking for in this book.

Comment: What is the difference between centralized and decentralized markets? Does this have to do only with the behaviour of market makers or not?

Comment: What is the context? please give the reference.